# Find a variable value with Solver function

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to set up a "Solver" function to find a normal depth of a channel (yn). The parameters are given in the code below, where I can estimate one side of the equation. All other parameters are function of yn. I need to find yn that solves the function A*(R^(2/3)=nQSo.

```
So=0.001                                       
n=0.013                                        
Q=30  
B=10 

nQSo=(n*Q)/(So^(1/2))

A=B*yn
P=B+2*yn
R=A/P

A*(R^(2/3)=nQSo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at `optimize`

```
So=0.001                                       
n=0.013                                        
Q=30  
B=10 

nQSo=(n*Q)/(So^(1/2))

error = function(yn,nQSo){
  A=B*yn
  P=B+2*yn
  R=A/P

  return(abs(A*(R^(2/3))-nQSo))
}

optimize(error,interval = c(0,2),nQSo = nQSo)
```

the result as you see is `yn = 1.239066`